# Windows Form: StackOverflowException

Tags: c#, forms, stack-overflow

I was building a windows form in Visual Studio 2010 using C#. I was getting the StackOverflowException when I hit the button. I found some alternative ways to solve this but had no luck.

`Program` is a class I created, and there's a `Execute` function within that class that's doing all the intense calculation and such.

```
private void execute_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Thread thread = new Thread(new ThreadStart(Execute));
    thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
    thread.Start();
}

private void Execute()
{
    Console.WriteLine("1111");
    Program p = new Program();
    p.function = "myNewFunction";
    p.inputfile = fileTextbox.Text;
    Console.WriteLine("2222");
    p.Execute(); //somehow never reaches here
}
```

When I run it, the console only prints out 1111. I'm really confused as to how assigning values could create StackOverflowException.

Please help! Thanks!

Comment: what are p.function and p.inputfile? fields or properties? Please add the code for these to your question.

Comment: @ChrisBallard they are just simple string values.

Comment: Can you post the code for the Program class.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suppose new Program() creates program, calls p.Execute() which again creates new Program() and call p.Execute and so on... infinite recursion leads to stack overflow.

Answer (score 3):

You appear to be calling `Execute()` from within `Execute()`.  This will result in a continuously growing stack as the process keeps placing new contexts of Execute on top of each other, endlessly calling Execute before the function actually finishes.  This leads to a `StackOverflowException`

Comment: I know this this is a bit confusing, but the Execute() function that I put in the example is not the same as p.Execute(), they are two different functions so it's not calling itself forever.

Comment: please add all the code, otherwise we are just guessing

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same exception but my answer might help someone else. I was using therads, timers, backgroundworker thread and graphics objects. So i was thinking that they are the culprits but once i removed Random() method. This exception stopped.